# I need help with this integer programming problem

Tags: integer-programming

I do not know how to solve this integer programming problem.
$$\min_{w_{i,j}} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^{N} w_{i,j}$$
$$s.t. \sum_{j=1,j \neq i}^{N} w_{i,j} \geq L, \forall i \in \left[ N \right]$$
$$w_{i,j} = w_{j,i}, \forall i \in \left[ N \right], j \in \left[ N \right], i \neq j$$
$$w_{i,j} \in \left[ S \right], \forall i \in \left[ N \right], j \in \left[ N \right], i \neq j$$

$L$ is a positive integer, $\left[ N \right]$ is a set of positive integers and $\left[ N \right] = \left\{ 1, 2, \dots, N \right\}$, $\left[ S \right]$ is a set of non-negative integers and $\left[ S \right] = \left\{0, 1,  \dots, N \right\}$

Answer (score 1):

You can use an integer programming package (e.g. `mips` in python) to solve the problem, first you need to define the variables in order to express the objective function and the constraints and define the parameter ($N, L$) values:

```
from sys import stdout
from mip import Model, xsum, INTEGER

N = 10
L = 2

model = Model()

w = [[model.add_var('w({},{})'.format(i, j), var_type=INTEGER, lb=0, ub=N)
      for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)]

model.objective = xsum(w[i][j]*(i!=j) for i in range(N) for j in range(N))

for i in range(N):
    model.add_constr(xsum(w[i][j]*(i!=j) for j in range(N)) >= L)
    
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        model.add_constr(w[i][j] == w[j][i])
    
model.optimize()

if model.num_solutions:
    stdout.write('\n')
    for i, v in enumerate(model.vars):
        stdout.write(str(int(v.x)))
        if i % N == N-1:
            stdout.write('\n')

# solution
# 0000000020
# 0000002000
# 0000100100
# 0000010001
# 0010000100
# 0001000001
# 0200000000
# 0010100000
# 2000000000
# 0001010000
```

The above solution to be interpreted as $w_{1,9}=2$, $w_{2,7}=2$, $w_{3,5}=w_{3,8}=1$ etc.